# '/usr/' versus '/usr/local/' for source installation

Tags: install-from-source, source-code

Are there any differences when you compile software and move it to either '/usr/local' or to the '/usr/' directories? Personally, I try to move everything to '/usr/local/' so I don't need to search for all of the prerequisites, but I notice that each source has different defaults. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `/usr/local/bin` appears first in your PATH, so if you have a command called `qwerty` in both those locations and run `qwerty` in a terminal, you will be executing the one in `/usr/local/bin`.

Personally I put all manually installed software in `/usr/local` so it does not clash with anything managed by `apt/dpkg`.

Comment: I hadn't even considered conflicting with `apt/dpkg`. Though, I try to install most things from source so I know the installation is complete and where everything is.

Comment: @WxPilot you can always see where every file installed through apt/dpkg is.

Comment: @muru Yes, but it is still inconvenient when you are compiling from source and you need to track down numerous prerequisite libraries. Much easier when they are only in one or two places.

Comment: @WxPilot if you say so.